# Simple Reusable workflow rejected

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, reusable

I am working on understanding how reusable workflows work, and I have come across an issue I can't quite solve.

I have a simple 2010 reusable workflow:
[image]

The workflow was associated with the ProjectContentType content type, and then once published i associated it with a list like such:
[image]

The Workflow error page, it just says rejected:
[image]

What is the reason for this "rejection"?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running as an approval workflow, you need to set the Content Approval Status and the Workflow Status as in the following 
[image]

This will create your action Plan and approve publishing for your ProjectContentType